# How to get rid of this dialog window in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am new to vscode and I'm running python in it. Is there a way to remove this?

[image]

I've tried to change many editor settings but nothing seems to work.

This is the current user settings file I have.

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0.8,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code medium",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
    "diffEditor.renderIndicators": false,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false,
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off"
}
```

As you can see I've tried to switch off many editor settings but nothing worked for me.

These are the current extensions I have.

[image: Extensions image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": false,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": false
},
```

Set the "`other`" to `false` to turn off those quicksuggestions.

Actually I think that is parameter and type info after closer inspection, so try:

```
"editor.parameterHints": false,
```

Comment: Not working bro... I've even tried "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": false,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": false
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": {
            "strings": false
        }
    },
    "python.linting.enabled": false